# regex matching patern accross lines and do find and replace

Tags: regex, replace

hi i have huge files with data like:

```
1234567890\t this is head row1 and some random text here... \r\n
12\t line1 some randomtexthere... \r\n
6549853695\t this is head row2 and some random text here... \r\n
6\t line1 some randomtexthere... \r\n
1\t line2 some randomtexthere... \r\n
54\t iine3 some randomtexthere... \r\n
2158965845\t this is head row3 and some random text here... \r\n
1\t line1 some randomtexthere... \r\n
25\t line2 some randomtexthere... \r\n
```

basically head and data rows... 
I need to add head number to all following rows till next head.
Data row count after head row may change anywhere from 1 to 200 rows!!!
Every data row begins with number from to 1-99 followed by tab
Every head row begins with ten digit number followed by tab.

currently have:
find:`(^(([0-9]{10}\t).*\r\n)((([0-9]{1})|([0-9]{2}))\t.*\r\n))`

replace with:`\2\3\4`

current option repeat find and replace using emeditor 200 times till everything is replaced... but considering huge amount of files and file sizes this takes insane amount of time...

any ideas for some magical solution?
final result should look like:

```
1234567890\t this is head row1 and some random text here... \r\n
1234567890\t12\t line1 some randomtexthere... \r\n
6549853695\t this is head row2 and some random text here... \r\n
6549853695\t6\t line1 some randomtexthere... \r\n
6549853695\t1\t line2 some randomtexthere... \r\n
6549853695\t54\t iine3 some randomtexthere... \r\n
2158965845\t this is head row3 and some random text here... \r\n
2158965845\t1\t line1 some randomtexthere... \r\n
2158965845\t25\t line2 some randomtexthere... \r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

with perl one-liner

```
perl -F'\t' -ape 'if ($F[0]=~/\d{10}/) { $id = $F[0]; } else { $_ = "$id\t$_"; }' <input_file >output_file
```

or modifying files inplace `-i`

```
perl -i.bak -F'\t' -ape 'if ($F[0]=~/\d{10}/) { $id = $F[0]; } else { $_ = "$id\t$_"; }' files
```

from perl -h

- -i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- -F/pattern/       split() pattern for -a switch (//'s are optional)
- -a                autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into @F)
- -p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
- -e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)